# JSpinner SpinnerDateModel question

Tags: java, swing, date, jspinner

I'm trying to create a JSpinner to enable the user to pick a Date. I want there to be a lower date limit and an upper date limit. I also want the initial value to be the lower date limit. Unfortunately, My problem is that it won't let me use the lower limit as the initial value (the JSpinner simply becomes unresponsive). Here is my code:

```
SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
model.setStart(minTime);  //lower limit
model.setEnd(maxTime);    //upper limit
model.setValue(minTime);  //doesn't like this!
model.setCalendarField(Calendar.MINUTE);
JSpinner timePicker = new JSpinner(model);
timePicker.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(timePicker, "HH:mm dd/MM/yy"));
```

If I set the initial value to be one minute before or after the lower limit, it works fine. But for my requirements, I do not want that.

Help?

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but you might want to try to use the GUI builder in NetBeans. It saved me a lot of time from configuring swing components by code. In your case, you can create a JSpinner and configure the "model" from the properties panel.

Comment: Maybe it saves you time, but I actually find it quicker (and the resultant code a lot cleaner/organised) doing it manually. I don't see how that would solve this problem anyway.

Comment: Not exactly what your looking for, but there is a sweet open source data picker at http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug to me.  I messed around with some code and it appears that whatever you pass to `setValue`, I'll call it `value`, must be at least one `calendarField` unit greater than `minTime`.

i.e. if you had used `model.setCalendarField(Calendar.YEAR)`, `value` would have to be any date in 2011, assuming you used a date in 2010 for `minTime`.

According to Sun, the invariant enforced by the SpinnerDateModel constructors is `minimum <= value <= maximum`, so this problem shouldn't be happening.

The first workaround that comes to mind is creating a custom `SpinnerDateModel` which overrides the `getPreviousValue()` and `setValue()` methods to manually check against your desired `minTime`.